# Pressing cancel in choose from list will cause a error

Tags: applescript

When I execute this script, everything works fine, but then when I press the cancel button, the script just give me a error, "Can’t get item 1 of false"

```
set mailList to {"Hide Applications", "Quit Applications", "Full Volume"}
set mailType to choose from list mailList

if item 1 of mailType is "Hide Applications" then
    tell application "Finder"
        set visible of every process whose visible is true and name is not "Finder" to false
        set the collapsed of windows to true
    end tell
else if item 1 of mailType is "Full Volume" then
    set volume output volume 100
else if item 1 of mailType is "Quit Applications" then
    tell application "System Events" to set the visible of every process to true
    
    set white_list to {"Finder"}
    
    try
        tell application "Finder"
            set process_list to the name of every process whose visible is true
        end tell
        repeat with i from 1 to (number of items in process_list)
            set this_process to item i of the process_list
            if this_process is not in white_list then
                tell application this_process
                    quit
                end tell
            end if
        end repeat
    on error
        tell the current application to display dialog "An error has occurred!" & return & "This script will now quit" buttons {"Quit"} default button 1 with icon 0
        
    end try
end if
```

Comment: Line 3 is asking for item 1 of mailType which implies a list. However, when you cancel, you don't get a list. Instead, you get `false`, and your error. There are probably several approaches but an obvious one would be to put the entire if…then inside a try block.

Answer (score 0):

You add a check if `mailType` is a boolean which would happen if you press cancel. The check would be inserted between line 2 and 3 and would look something like this:

```applescript
...
if class of mailType = boolean then return
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`choose from list` returns boolean `false` when the Cancel button is pressed.

Just abort the script immediately in this case

```
set mailType to choose from list mailList
if mailType is false then return
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying every possible answer to it!